# json_normalize a nested database

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to flatten a json database into pandas dataframe and as it's the first time I'm dealing with json format, I can't do what I want.
The database is located here https://mtgjson.com/downloads/all-files/#allprices and according to the model, the structure is like this :

```
{
  "0120a941-9cfb-50b5-b5e4-4e0c7bd32410": {
    "mtgo": {
      "cardhoarder": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "retail": {
          "foil": {
            ..., // more rows
            "2020-04-21": 0.02
          },
          "normal": {
            ..., // more rows
            "2020-04-21": 0.02
          }
        }
      },
    },
    "paper": {
      "cardkingdom" : {
        "buylist": {
          "foil": {
            ..., // more rows
            "2020-04-21": 0.6
          },
          "normal": {
            ..., // more rows
            "2020-04-21": 0.01
          }
        },
        "currency": "USD",
        "retail": {
          "foil": {
            ..., // more rows
            "2020-04-21": 0.12
          },
          "normal": {
            ..., // more rows
            "2020-04-21": 0.02
          }
        }
      },
      "cardmarket": {
        "currency": "EUR",
        "retail": {
          "foil": {
            ..., // more rows
            "2020-04-21": 0.12
          },
          "normal": {
            ..., // more rows
            "2020-04-21": 0.02
          }
        }
      },
      "tcgplayer": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "retail": {
          "foil": {
            ..., // more rows
            "2020-04-21": 0.12
          },
          "normal": {
            ..., // more rows
            "2020-04-21": 0.02
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I look into the json file I have this :

```
{"meta": {"date": "2021-11-07", "version": "5.1.0+20211107"}, "data": {"00010d56-fe38-5e35-8aed-518019aa36a5": {"paper": {"cardkingdom": {"buylist": {"foil.....
```

When I do the basic `pd.read_json('AllPrices.json')` I got this

|  | meta | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| date | 2021-11-07 | NaN |
| version | 5.1.0+20211107 | NaN |
| 00010d56-fe38-5e35-8aed-518019aa36a5 | NaN | {'paper': {'cardkingdom': {'buylist': {'foil':... |
| 0001e0d0-2dcd-5640-aadc-a84765cf5fc9 | NaN | {'paper': {'cardkingdom': {'buylist': {'normal... |

So I did some research and found the `json_normalize` and wrote this piece of code :

```
with open('AllPrices.json','r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
pd.json_normalize(data, errors='ignore')
```

This did the job by flattening the json database but I ended with one row and 31 millions columns. What I want is only one information in this database that is the uuid and the cardmarket price of a normal paper card on the date I want like this :

| uuid | paper.cardmarket.retail.normal.2021-11-07 |
| --- | --- |
| 00010d56-fe38-5e35-8aed-518019aa36a5 | 0.5 |
| 0001e0d0-2dcd-5640-aadc-a84765cf5fc9 | 0.25 |

I played with the `record_path =`  parameter and the `meta =` parameter but the best I did was not my expected table.
I tried `record_path = ['data']` that give me only the uuid in one column.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, use `json_normalize` for each `uuid` record then extract the desired information 'paper.cardmarket.retail.normal':

```
with open('AllPrices.json') as fp:
    prices = json.load(fp)

    data = []
    for uuid in prices['data']:
        df = pd.json_normalize(prices['data'][uuid]) \
               .filter(like='paper.cardmarket.retail.normal')
        if df.empty:
            continue
        df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('.', 1).str[-1]
        df.index = [uuid]
        data.append(df)
    df = pd.concat(data)
```

Output: (tested on `AllPrices.json` file)

```
                                      2021-08-09  2021-08-11  2021-08-12  2021-08-13  ...  2021-10-27  2021-10-28  2021-11-02  2021-11-09
00010d56-fe38-5e35-8aed-518019aa36a5        4.35        4.35        4.35        4.35  ...        4.35        4.35        4.35        4.35
0001e0d0-2dcd-5640-aadc-a84765cf5fc9        4.95        4.95        3.45        3.45  ...        7.99        6.81        5.42        6.77
0003caab-9ff5-5d1a-bc06-976dd0457f19        0.24        0.27        0.07        0.38  ...        0.25        0.04        0.13        0.36
0003d249-25d9-5223-af1e-1130f09622a7        0.30        0.30        0.75        0.75  ...        0.15        0.20        0.04        0.25
0004a4fb-92c6-59b2-bdbe-ceb584a9e401        0.27        0.14        0.19        0.10  ...        0.10        0.05        0.19        0.13
...                                          ...         ...         ...         ...  ...         ...         ...         ...         ...
fffa4ccf-733e-513a-98f9-181b9549de62        0.23        0.15        0.21        0.21  ...        0.10        0.21        0.15        0.20
fffb659e-b3fa-5cd8-9423-fe5ac74248b5        0.49        0.49        0.49        0.49  ...        0.35        0.35        0.35        0.20
fffbc95a-c4d1-56aa-8653-8a7c71fe19ce        6.95        6.95        6.95        6.95  ...       10.26       10.26       10.26        6.43
fffc1305-a118-559b-9504-3d7b56ca0bde        0.18        0.18        0.18        0.18  ...        0.04        0.04        0.04        0.04
fffdd333-3789-5104-a8be-37be199a2cb1        0.87        0.73        0.99        0.99  ...        0.49        0.45        0.45        0.15

[50568 rows x 75 columns]
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem? Now I can know the prices of my decks. lol :)

Comment: It works perfectly and is better than I expected as I can see the price evolution ! Thank you very much.